# show UIViewController using UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

```
 self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

self.pageController.dataSource = self;
[[self.pageController view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];

MainScreenViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];

[self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

[self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
[[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
[self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

This show me page like this

[image]

I want a new UIViewController on every movement of scrolling page. How can I do it?

Comment: [https://github.com/ddeville/DDPageControl](https://github.com/ddeville/DDPageControl) See this link download this projcet.you get exact idea of page control...

Comment: I saw this, again on controller, can I move different UIViewController like this?

Comment: yes sure you can do this...

Comment: See the Above Code, which I posted, It one controller, whose many objects are stored and shows with index number.